# Performance of 'buffer[k%length]' vs 'buffer[k] catch ArrayIndexOutOfBounds'

Tags: java, android, performance

A simple question about java performance. If I write a loop

```
for(int i=0;i<n;++i) buffer[(k++)%buffer.length]=something;
```

in which something is a non trivial digital filter. With this code I have a modulo operation at every write. This feels a bit silly because the Java VM will check that anyway. Therefore I would assume that a consturct using an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds would be faster (the buffer contains 1'000'000 numbers, so we won't have that overflow too often)

```
int i;
try
  {
  for(i=0;i<n;++i,++k) buffer[k]=something;
  }
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds e)
  {
  k=0;
  for(;i<n;++i,++k) buffer[k]=something;
  }
```

A third solution could be to calculate in advance at what point we would overflow and then split the loop manually in two. The code to determine how far the loop can go is executed every 768 samples, so from that perspective it might be slower than the catch method.

The problem here, aside from the silly duplication of code, which I will gladly sacrifice on the altar of performance, is that we have *more* code. And there it often appears that java doesn't optimize as well as with smaller routines.

So my question is: what strategy is the most performant ? Anybody experience with this type of construct ? Also, can anybody shed a light on the performance on android devices of both constructs ?

Comment: Why don't you include `k < buffer.length` as one of the loop conditions? What are you omitting here? – it sure looks like a simple `Arrays.fill(buffer, something)` would work here.

Comment: A million modulo operations should not be very noticeable performance wise...

Comment: Because it is still a comparison. I wouldn't expect k%length vs k<length to change much. However omitting the % might, which is the question. This is an example of code for filters. The something part is not that trivial. A plain Array.fill or Array.copy won't work.

Comment: Why don't you try both and measure the result?

Comment: I could, I'm just lazy and assuming someone wants to score some credits. Aside, it is a question that maybe other people have an interest in as well.

Comment: Wow: either of your options seem to be maintenance pains - why not just use the right length in the for loop?

Comment: because it is a calculation in front of the loop which is also repeated a fair amount of times. Maybe I should extend the question to include that.

Comment: I would expect that `if (k >= buffer.length) k = 0;` is the best option. It's short, safe, and doesn't repeat the code. The branch predictor should make the test essentially free.

Comment: FYI, exceptions are _expensive._  Never _expect_ to throw an exception in your code.

Comment: why buffer.length? better get the length before the loop, otherwise you are calling buffer.length in each loop

Comment: FWIW, `buffer.length` isn't a method call -- in Dalvik it turns into an `array-length` instruction.  Since it's a constant, the JIT compiler can generate code that obtains the value once, before entering the loop.  Clever compilers could even do that for method calls on common standard classes (e.g. `String.length()`).  Calling a `size` method on a generic collection class is a very different story.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer depends on your target platform.  You've added the Android tag, so I'm going to answer in terms of Dalvik and (let's say) a Nexus 4.

First, the ARMv7-A architecture doesn't provide integer division instructions.  Your modulus will be computed in software every time through the loop, which is going to slow you down a bit.  (This is why it's best to use power-of-2 sizes for hash tables -- you can use a bit mask rather than a mod.)

Second, throwing an exception is expensive.  The VM has to create the exception object, and initialize it with a snapshot of the current stack.  In addition to the immediate overhead, you're creating X number of objects that have to be cleaned up later, and increasing the possibility that the VM will have to stop you mid-computation and collect garbage.

Third, generally speaking, any computation you can pull out of the inner loop represents a win, so manually testing for array overrun on every loop iteration is unsatisfying.  You don't want to add a test for `k` vs. `length` to the loop header or body if you can avoid it.  (A JIT compiler may do something like this -- if it can tell that the array index never walks off the end of the array, it doesn't have to do a per-element bounds check.)

Based on the (still slightly vague) sense of what you're doing and how many times you're doing it, I'd say the best option is to compute the "break" position ahead of the loop, and iterate the necessary number of times.

I'm curious to know how this turns out in practice. :-)

Comment: Hey, that's a cool trick. Just by alinging my buffers to powers of two and using a & operator I was able to speed up the program with about 10%. Great tip !